# Prevent from adding/append input type="button" if submitted field is empty

Tags: jquery

I have this simple html project of adding list from inputted field

```
<div class="container">
    <input id="list-input" />
    <button id="add">Add To List</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Your List</h1>
    <ul id="mylist">

    </ul>
    <button id="clear">clear</button>
</div>
```

and below is how I manage my jquery in adding list

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    //add to list function
    $('#add').click(function(){
        var newToList = $('#list-input').val();

        $('#mylist').append('<li id="item">' + newToList  + '<button id="remove"/></button>' + '</li>');

        if(newToList == ""){
            alert("Please input some list to do");
        }
        //clear input field
        $('#list-input').val('');
    });

});
```

Each time i submitted an empty field an alert will return but button i append still shows. Is there a way on how can i append the field value with a button next to it, where if the field is empty it wont show both field value and the button next to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return false after the alert.

```
$('#add').click(function(){
    var newToList = $('#list-input').val();

   if(newToList == ""){
        alert("Please input some list to do");
         return false;
    }
    $('#mylist').append('<li id="item">' + newToList  + '<button id="remove"/></button>' + '</li>');



    //clear input field
    $('#list-input').val('');

});
```